# How to keep asking user for input until I get an integer in a specific range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, error-handling, while-loop

I recently decided to revisit my TicTacToe game which I made approx 3 months ago with a fresh set of eyes to debug, and there is this one bug in particular which keeps getting to me. Basically, I have this code:

```
def player_choice(board):
    '''Asks the player for their next position, calls a func to check if it's free'''
    '''and returns the position if it's free for later use'''
    spot = None
    while spot not in range(1, 10) or not space_check(board, spot):
        try:
            spot = int(input("Choose your next position (1-9): "))
        except:
            print("Hmm, looks to me like your input was invalid")
        else:
            break
    return spot
```

This is a function in the greater scheme of things, but what breaks the whole game is the fact that I need an **integer** as an input, strictly in range **between 1 and 10**. Before trying error handling I used a while loop that kept on asking for an int if a str was given:

```
spot = int(input("Choose your next position (1-9): "))
    while spot not in range (1, 10) or not space_check(board, spot):
        spot = int(input("Looks like the spot you're trying to choose is invalid!\nPlease choose another position (1-9): "))
    return spot
```

But then I switched to this version and here it won't accept a str as input, but it will accept an int outside of the 1-10 range. My question is: what can I do to make this work the way I need, to take an integer strictly between 1 and 10 and keep on asking until precisely this input is provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a few things around, this seems to work. Although I do not know why the `else` is always triggered...

```
def player_choice2(board):
    '''Asks the player for their next position, calls a func to check if it's free'''
    '''and returns the position if it's free for later use'''
    try:
        spot = int(input("Choose your next position (1-9): "))
    except:
        print("Hmm, looks to me like your input was invalid")
        spot = 0
    while spot not in range(1, 10) or not space_check(board, spot):
        try:
            spot = int(input("Choose your next position **  (1-9) **: "))
        except:
            print("Hmm, looks to me like your input was invalid")
        else:
            # This always fires...?
            print("Else....")
    return spot
```

Comment: Thanks plenty!! This does work, and I'm a bit dumbfounded how a little adjustment snapped everything into place. The only hitch is that now the terminal won't quit when I use Ctrl+C, oh well 

Comment: Oh, and I figured out that else would always fire because the condition was to input an int, but 45 or 95429 is an int, so there was no error, but the condition for the loop was not satisfied, thus the error would not fire, but the loop would keep on running still. It also explains why there will be an error if I try typing in any str instead though.

Answer (score 0):

```
spot = " "
while ord(spot) not in [49,58]:
    spot = input("Looks like the spot you're trying to choose is 
invalid!\nPlease choose another position (1-9): ")
    try:
       spot = ord(spot)
    excpet:
       spot = " "
return spot
```

What I did here is check for the ascii value of the spot which should be number and numbers are 1->49, 2->50 and so on.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately after trying this one out, I can say it doesn't work for whatever reason, and keeps on repeatedly printing that the spot I'm trying to choose is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
    def player_choice(board):
        '''Asks the player for their next position, calls a func to check if it's free'''
        '''and returns the position if it's free for later use'''
        spot = True
        while spot in range(1, 10) or not space_check(board, spot):
            try:
                spot = int(input("Choose your next position (1-9): "))
            except:
                break
        else:
            print("Hmm, looks to me like your input was invalid")
    
        return spot
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not... This loop approves of a random number extremely out of range, which is something exactly I'm trying to work against